# Which one of $|z|, |z|^2$ is the complex modulus?

Tags: complex-numbers

Some texts appear to define the complex modulus as the magnitude, that is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ of any complex number $z = x + iy$. Other texts seem to define the modulus as the square of that number, in other words the magnitude squared, or the product of $z$ and conjugate $\bar{z}$.

> Which one of $|z|, |z|^2$ is the complex modulus?

Let $z = 3 + 4i$. Is modulus $|z|$ equal to $5$ or $25$ ?

Comment: The modulus is defined everywhere as $|z|$. I've never seen it defined as $|z|^2$. Which text?

Comment: The term *norm* is used in both these senses while *modulus* is synonymous to just one of them, so we shouldn't be dismissing this question if the OP is translating into English.

Answer (score 5):

The modulus of $z = x+iy$ is defined to be $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Thus in your case $x = 3,y = 4 \implies |z| = 5$.